# Autoflow not working on absolute positioned div in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to build a timeline to display a series of events, there may be many events added to the timeline so its container is set to autoflow, for visual purposes I have the code here: http://codepen.io/tomevans1664/pen/QyLObL. This all works fine in chrome, but in IE the vertical timeline bar is not bound by the overflow.

HTML:

```
    <div class="center">
        <div class="timeline">
            <div class="line">
            </div>
            <div class="content"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.center{

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: none;
}
.line{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    background: #d7e4ed;
}
.content{
    height: 1000px;
}
.timeline{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

IE Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzQTx.jpg

Comment: what is `overflow-x:none;` supposed to be?

Comment: that was jus me tying to remove the scrollbar in ie, feel free to change the two separate overflows to overflow: auto

Answer (score 0):

So it appears, for IE, that to overflow absolutely positioned content, the containing div that has the overflow attribute must also use absolute positioning, although this does break the auto margin.

To get .center centered again i used:

```
left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```